# Column Auto Filter Graphically

Tags: sql, sql-server

How I filter SQL Server column data filter like all the word which starts from a or A come on first line Like B or b come on the second.

```
Create Table Table_my
(
  C1 varchar(50)
  , C2 varchar(50)
  , 
)

Select*
From Table_my
WHERE C1 Like '[ABC]%';
```

Comment: Simply `C1 like 'ABC%';`. Use a case insensitive collation to get both upper and lower case match, or do `UPPER(C1) like 'ABC%';`

Comment: what is complete query

Comment: Just like the one you have, just adjust the like pattern! Or have I got it all wrong?

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result, all as formatted text (no images.) Read [mcve] before you start!

Comment: dear i do this but i got error

Comment: Create Table Table_my
(
C1 varchar(50)
, C2 varchar(50)
, 
)

Select*
From Table_my
UPPER(C1) like 'ABC%';

Comment: dear this code can not run

Comment: You forgot the `WHERE`.

Comment: Send me the complete code

Comment: Create Table Table_my
(
C1 varchar(50)
, C2 varchar(50)
, 
)

Select*
From Table_my
WHERE UPPER(C1) like 'ABC%';

Comment: This Code Donot Work

Comment: i need word graphically

Comment: Do you mean "alphabetically" instead of "graphically"? Just add an `order by C1` to your query.

Comment: yes i need graphically when i type in the table then auto filter

Comment: @HazratAli, please look at the logic what I have mentioned below ...

Answer (score 0):

I'm giving the logic how we can achieve this ,you can change as per requirement , please check below query..

```
SELECT 
 CASE WHEN C1 Like 'A%' THEN C1 END AS a,
 CASE WHEN C1 Like 'B%' THEN C1 END  AS b
 FROM Table_my
```

You can take column C1 and C2 as well ,this is the way we can achieve not exact solution.

Comment: Create Table Table_my
(
  C1 varchar(50)
  , C2 varchar(50)
  , 
)
SELECT 
 CASE WHEN C1 Like 'A%' THEN C1 END AS a,
 CASE WHEN C1 Like 'B%' THEN C1 END  AS b
 FROM Table_my